# Miss understanding between class and interface in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

As i know we should use `implements`  for interfaces in typescript, and we use `extends` for class. but I face with a snippet code which implemented a class in this tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 impelent , and my question is can we implement a class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please quote the parts of the linked tutorial that relate to your question **in** your question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Classes can be used as interfaces in TypeScript.

Comment: are you both brother and sister? your second name and country suggest that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically due to the fact the visibility of private members are scoped to the type, and not the instance.

Allowing the private fields to be missing would be an enormous problem, not some trivial soundness issue. Consider this code:

```
class Identity {
  private id: string = "secret agent";
  public sameAs(other: Identity) {
    return this.id.toLowerCase() === other.id.toLowerCase();
  }
}

class MockIdentity implements Identity {
  public sameAs(other: Identity) { return false; }
}
```

`MockIdentity` is a public-compatible version of Identity but attempting to use it as one will crash in same As when a non-mocked copy interacts with a mocked copy.

```
// Real class
class Foo {

    public writeToFile(){
        fileWriter.writeToFile('');
    }
}

// Mock
class MockFoo implements Foo {

     public writeToFile(){
         // do nothing
     }
}
```